# Separate y axis for different facets in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a plot using ggplot where different facets should have different y axis limits. By default each facet has the same y axis values. can this be changed somehow?

Comment: `scales` argument in facet

Answer (score 28):

You can change `scales` to "free_y" instead.

```
  facet_grid(facets, margins = FALSE, scales = "fixed",
    space = "fixed", shrink = TRUE,
    labeller = "label_value", as.table = TRUE, drop = TRUE)
```

For further detail and examples, see: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/

Answer (score 12):

See `?facet_grid`. You want to use the argument `scales="free_y"`.